# What is opening and closing in computer vision

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, mathematical-morphology

What would be an explanation for opening and closing in computer vision?
I am trying to get a well grounded explanation.

Comment: Do you mean this opening? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opening_%28morphology%29

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are morphological operations.  Opening is [erosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erosion_(morphology)) followed by [dilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilation_(morphology)). Closing is dilation followed by erosion.  For binary images, opening removes small connected components and small protrusions. Closing fills in small holes and gaps between connected components.